# Linux script to select an option & download resulting file from web page

Tags: bash, web, download

Is there any way to write a linux script to press a button on a webpage and download the file generated?
Here is the website..
http://kos.twojeip.net

I need to write a script that presses "Pobierz wszystkie"  (Download ALL), Its the 3rd button from the left on top....

I was playing with lynx & wget but not having any joy as there are no html links..

Comment: Under Firefox, press the button, download the file, look at the download history, right-click the file, select "Copy download link". That's the link you want to `wget`.

Comment: @MiklosAubert That should probably be an answer

Comment: If there are no html links you will have to figure out the URL with a tool like FireBug and then pass that to wget.

Comment: The right click & copy download link only gives me a load of these...  download[]=pack-abscbn&download[]=pack-akta&download[]=pack-austriasat&download[]=pack-bis....  When I wget that string after the web address, I get loads of `-bash: download[]: bad array subscript` and produces a file `download.php?download[]=pack-abscbn` that has only a few entries..

Comment: @Jim Garrison..  There are no links, the file is generated online, I want to get a script to request the file to be generated & downloaded..  Have you had a look at the site m8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is enclose the extremely long URL in double quotes and use the `-O` (upper-case letter O) option to wget:

```
wget -O output.txt "http://.... extremely long URL "
```